# How to manage deeper segmented url in CodeIgniter properly?

Tags: php, url-routing, codeigniter-2, remap

I would like to know if it's possible out of the box in **CodeIgniter2** to create the urls without modifying `routes.php` for each controller's function like this:

1. `backend.website.com/ecommerce/products/edit/$id`
2. `backend.website.com/ecommerce/currencies/form/$id`
3. `backend.website.com/ecommerce/customers/partners/etc/$arg1/$arg2`

My `controllers/ecommerce.php` for `function products()` is something like this:

```
public function products($page = 0, $items = NULL, $subview = NULL)
{

    if($subview != NULL){
        // This function is localhost/ecommerce/products/form/$some_id
        _remap($subview); // gives me an error


    }else{
    // Default view with pagination arguments $page and $items

    // Page settings
    $this->config->set_item('page_name',    'Products');
    $this->config->set_item('page_subname', 'Product listing table');

    // Request items
    $this->data['items'] = $this->ecommerce_model->get_products(array('page' => $page, 'items' => $items));

    // Creating a view
    $this->data['view'] = $this->load->view('/ecommerce/products/index', $this->data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('/_templates/default/index', $this->data);

    }
}

public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method == 'form')
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
        // SKIP
    }
}
```

I found that default `_remap()` function could be useful, but I do not understand how to use it with my function.

Does anyone have any experience with that and could provide some little sample?

**==== UPDATED ====**

Is it even possible for `_remap()` to work with another functions such as `orders()`, `customers()`, `currencies()`, etc... at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to complicate things that much for something like this.

Just add another parameter to each of your methods, for example `$action`:

```
public function products($action = false, $page = 0, $items = NULL, $subview = NULL) { 

    switch($action) {

        case 'edit':
            // edit stuff here
            break;

        case 'something else':
           // other stuff
           break;
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: please, could you explain, how to use it with CI pagination ? when i click on 2nd page, it will redirect to `/ecommerce/products/25`. Now 25 becomes `$action = 25`, and will ignore the rest. Is it possible to make it work with `$action` at the same time ?

Comment: I haven't used pagination for a while, let me get back to you in a few minutes... But it has to be possible to do it, I think it's something to do with url_segment.

Comment: Yup, I was right, read more in the docs, but you should use `$config['uri_segment']`. 3 is the default value, you should go with 4...

Comment: perfect i will try that out in a while! thank you very much Shomz!